# NestJS accessing private class field before testing method with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, nestjs

Assuming there is the following nest service class with the **private** field *myCache* and the public method *myFunction*:

```
import * as NodeCache from 'node-cache'
class MyService{
    private myCache = new NodeCache();

    myFunction() {
        let data = this.myCache.get('data');
        if(data === undefined){
            // get data with an http request and store it in this.myCache with the key 'data'
        } 
        return data;
    }
}
```

I want to test the function *myFunction* for two different cases.
Fist case: If condition is true. Second Case: If condition is false.

Here is the test class with the two missing tests:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MyService} from './myService';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [MyService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<MyService>(MyService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('myFunction', () => {
      it('should return chached data', () => {
          // first test
      }),
      it('should return new mocked data', () => {
          // second test
      })
   })
});
```

**Therefore I guess I have to access or mock the *myCache* private class field.**
Because it is private I can't access it in the test class.

My Question is: What's the best and correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Private members can be accessed as `service['myCache']`. There may be no need to do this, instead mock the source of data that needs to be mocked,which is NodeCache.

Comment: Ok, now I know how I could access it, but how I can actually mock this in the correct way with jest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking to mock it, you can always use `as any` to tell Typescript to not warn you about accessing private values.

```js
jest.spyOn((service as any).myCache, 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(someValue);
```

However, that's kind of annoying to have to do over and over again and not really the best practice. What I would do instead is move your cache to be an injectable provider so that it could be swapped out at a moments notice and your `MyService` no longer has a hard dependency on `node-cache`. Something like this:

```js
// my.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [
    MyService,
    {
      provide: 'CACHE',
      useClass: NodeCache
    }
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}

// my.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject('CACHE') private readonly myCache: NodeCache) {}
...
```

And now in your test you can swap out the `CACHE` token for a mock implementation that can also be retrieved in your `beforeEach` block, meaning no more any.

```js
describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let cache: { get; set; }; // you can change the type here
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        {
          provide: 'CACHE',
          useValue: { get: jest.fn(), set: jest.fn() }
        }
      ]
    }).compile();
    service = modRef.get(MyService);
    cache = modRef.get<{ get; set; }>('CACHE');
  });
});
```

And now you can call `jest.spyOn(cache, 'get')` without the use of `as any`.

Comment: It can be handled by DI but this can be handled with Jest alone, there's nothing annoying in a spy. For mocking per one test, it can be mocked once in `beforeEach`. For mocking in multiple tests there are `__mocks__` for reusable mocks.

Comment: It could be, but if you need to change the mock each time in the tests you'd have to continue to use the `jest.spyOn((service as any).myCache, 'get')` that I had in the beginning, which loses type safety and takes up more time writing

Comment: If `NodeCache` is already mocked, you can do `mockImplementation` on methods and probably re-import mocked module per test to get fresh mock. This is what Jest offers out of the box and it's not more bulky than Nest's DI overhead. DI is a killer feature with Jasmine and Angular, but it's harder to sell in Jest where Node modules can be easily mocked.